# Efficiently plot a real-time waveform

Tags: .net, wpf, performance, graph, plot

I'm plotting a waveform in WPF using the following XAML:

```
<Canvas>
    <Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="3">
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry>
                <PathFigure x:Name="figure" IsClosed="False">
                    <PathFigure.Segments>
                        <PolyLineSegment x:Name="polyline"/>
                    </PathFigure.Segments>
                </PathFigure>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
</Canvas>
```

I have a simple timer runnign every 32 ms that does nothing more than to add a random point to the line:

```
private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     xPos++;
     polyline.Points.Add(new Point(xPos, yPos + ((int)(rnd.NextDouble() * 10) - 5)));
}
```

This works fine, but as soon as I do the same thing with more than 10 lines, the CPU usage goed through the roof.

Upon inspecting the application with the WPF Profiler (Perforator), I can see that WPF marks the entire PathGeometry as a 'dirty region', instead of just updating the changes to the screen. So instead of noticing only a single pixel was changed, it redraws almost the complete form on each update.

I don't know if this is the reason for the excessive CPU usage, but can someone tell me how to optimize this (very simple) program, or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you ever remove a few points from the polylines?

Answer (score 0):

For real-time plotting you are probably better off using something more low level which lets you directly invoke simple drawing operations, a [`DrawingVisual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingvisual.aspx) might work.